# Problem in loading map to Georeferencer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm trying to load a map to the Georeferencer in QGIS using the approach from http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html. I try to get the locality coordinates(lat/lon) of the 'Stetson Pit' and 'Ponzer' on the map.

However, when I set all the points on the map and start georeferencing, it shows "transform failed: failed to compute GCP transform" transform not solvable"

May I know if it is possible to get coordinates of those sites from this map. Am I setting the CRS wrong (WQS84)??

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the `Settings` dialogue, and maybe a link to the source image?

Comment: I was able to georeference your image, I am using Lyon under win10 64 osgeo install. I was not able to reproduce the error...

Comment: I got it after updating to win 10 and using Lyon instead of the older versions. thanks!

Comment: Screenshot: https://flic.kr/p/BJwg6b

Comment: Link to image: https://flic.kr/p/BrYQdb